# Specific subring with non-zero unity element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I'm trying to find an example of a ring with unity $1\ne 0$ that has a subring with non-zero unity $1' \ne 1$.

Any hints here?

Thanks a lot,
Mariogs

Comment: As a note, this depends on your definitions of rings and subrings. If you are working with unitary rings, then a "subring" is required to contain the unity element which must be unique. I believe what you are looking for is a "subrng" (treating the ring as a rng) with a unity element on the subrng. This unity element is then NOT a unity element of the whole ring.

Comment: @user147209: can you please explain (me) a bit this distinction *ring* vs. *rng*?

Comment: @MattAllegro Here is an article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rng_(algebra). Most authors (and myself) require a _ring_ to have a unity element in its structure, in which case a subring requires the same unity element. A _rng_ does not have this requirement, and hence subrngs will not require a unity element, and if it does happens to have one, it does not have to be a unity element of the rng.

Answer (score 2):

Choose any ring with unity -- let's say $\mathbb{Z}$ just for the sake of argument -- and consider  $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.  This is a ring with unit element $(1,1)$.  Now consider the subring consisting of all elements of the form $(a,0)$.  You can take it from there...

Comment: I agree that (1,1) isn't going to be of the form (a, 0) but ahh, so unity for this subring is (1,0), yes?

Comment: Yes, but note user147209's comment above.  Normally we define "subring" as a subset of a ring that is also a ring *with respect to the same operations and with the same identity* as the larger ring.  What you have here is a subset that is a ring with respect to the same operations but *not* the same identity element, so that would normally not be considered a subring. It would, however, be a subrng; "rng" is the word for a ring that does not necessarily have a unit (it's missing the I, get it?). So a subrng is a subset that is a rng w.r.t. the same operations, but need not share the unit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the subrng of $\,2\times 2\,$ matrices having  form $\ \left[\begin{array}{}r & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right]$